# ReactJS: Destructure Data in Class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

So I have a file called Context.js which looks like the following:

```
const AppContext = createContext({
  
  // ... scheme colour palette
  color1: '#ADBDDB',
  color2: '#7F8EB2',
  color3: '#546287',
  color4: '#384366',

  // ... grey colour palette
  grey1: '#FFFFFF',
  grey7: '#2A3033',

  // ... Nexus back-end constants
  nexusIP: '126.0.0.2',
```

I want to import that file onto another component and use the "nexusIP" in that component. However, it is giving me issues. This is what I tried to do:

```
import Context from '../context/AppContext';
import React, { useContext, useState , Component } from 'react';

const { nexusIP, color5, grey1 } = useContext(AppContext);

class TempsAndTime extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            bedTempDisplay: props.bedTemp,
            bedTempUser: props.bedTemp,
            hotEndTempDisplay: props.hotEndTemp,
            hotEndTempUser: props.hotEndTemp,
            pcBootTimeStamp: props.pcBootTimeStamp,
            pcId: props.pcId,
            hotEndTempCondition: null,
            bedTempCondition: null
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        let bedTempIcon;
        let hotEndTempIcon;

        return (
            <div className={classes.container} >
                <div className={classes.timeContainer} >
                    <Typography className={classes.timeElapsed}>
                        Time elapsed
                    </Typography>
                </div>
            <div>
       );
}}
```

So I tried to destructure the value from that other Context.js file into this file but it was not letting me to do so. Any ideas?

Comment: I think `useContext` must be used inside a function component.

Comment: how would you do it for a class component then?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496563/how-to-use-react-context-inside-function-of-class-component could be of help? (I've stopped using class components myself)

Answer (score 0):

according to React documentation you can't use hook inside a class component nor outside of a functional component. so, try with functional component and definitely call inside the component, otherwise consume the context as [React suggest with render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer)